# Is it possible to change Alt_R+8 = bracketleft to Alt_L+8 = bracketleft

Tags: xmodmap

When pressing <kbd>Alt_R</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> it prints `XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 34` and I started to wonder if it's possible to emulate this with different key combo.

It's a pain to output brackets using right alt and I'm looking to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [xbindkeys](https://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html) + [xvkbd](http://t-sato.in.coocan.jp/xvkbd/).

`~/.xbindkeysrc`

```
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '('"
    Alt + 8
```

Comment: Isn't `Alt_R`+`8` this `[` instead of `(`  ?